# Как в aiogram3 можно сохранять и отправлять видео-куржки?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Мне нужно сохранить file id или скачать кружок, который пользователь будет отправлять боту, а потом, отправить этот видео-кружок обратно. Как это можно сделать в aiogram3? Заранее большое спасибо!